# slow joomla with many articles in database

Tags: performance, joomla

i have a joomla 3 site with more than 20000 articles, but it is very slow in loading, i have a VDS server with one Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU L5520 @ 2.27GHz and 1922208 kB memory running cent os 6,
and i have to remove all modules to speed up that, in every load, memory usage of httpd and mysqld processes increases to max.
i enabled cache in joomla's global configuration and it make better a little but still it is slow. what i can do for speed up joomla ( i think i will have more than 50000 articles ).

Answer (score 1):

1. turn on the cache plugin (this is different to the global config cache setting as it stores entire pages)
2. turn on gzip compression in global configuration.
3. turn on gzip compression on the server (will need to be on for joomla and server to work).

Comment: thanks but i did them and yes, performance is better but my main problem is huge count of articles that needs big ram and cpu, my server is limited and in bigger database it will be more essential to have more powerful hardware, is it there any way that joomla use only some of last ( in past month) added articles and others used when some user want them?